Bus error (core dumped) on several apps
I'm encountering a weird behaviour with my endeavourOS system.
For context, it seems to have started happening after a malformed svg file made inkscape and my system crash, after which I needed to hard-reboot it.
With several apps (to list the last few I've tested : flameshot, keepassxc, quiterss) I've had a Bus error (core dumped) message in the terminal and nothing more. With a bit of googling, I understood I need to use gdb but I cannot make sense of its output :
$ gdb flameshot
[...]
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from flameshot...

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
  <https://debuginfod.archlinux.org>
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n]) y
Debuginfod has been enabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled on' to .gdbinit.
Reading symbols from /home/user/.cache/debuginfod_client/b8258803335f21d12df1003c59200a5afb4dc585/debuginfo...                                                                                                                              

(gdb) run flameshot
Starting program: /usr/bin/flameshot flamshot
Downloading separate debug info for system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7fc6000                                                                                                                                                                 
Download failed: Connection reset by peer.  Continuing without separate debug info for system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7fc6000.                                                                                                             

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
memset () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S:244
244             VMOVU   %VMM(0), (%rdi)
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(gdb) backtrace
#0  memset () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S:244
#1  0x00007ffff7fcf524 in _dl_map_segments (loader=0x7fffffffd300, has_holes=<optimized out>, maplength=<optimized out>, nloadcmds=<optimized out>, loadcmds=<optimized out>, type=<optimized out>, header=0x8, fd=<optimized out>, 
    l=0x7ffff7f89530) at ./dl-map-segments.h:176
#2  _dl_map_object_from_fd (name=name@entry=0x555555569361 "libQt5Widgets.so.5", origname=origname@entry=0x0, fd=<optimized out>, fbp=fbp@entry=0x7fffffffd3a0, realname=<optimized out>, loader=loader@entry=0x7ffff7ffe2e0, 
    l_type=<optimized out>, mode=<optimized out>, stack_endp=<optimized out>, nsid=<optimized out>) at dl-load.c:1258
#3  0x00007ffff7fd0b01 in _dl_map_object (loader=<optimized out>, name=0x555555569361 "libQt5Widgets.so.5", type=1, trace_mode=<optimized out>, mode=0, nsid=<optimized out>) at dl-load.c:2249
#4  0x00007ffff7fca865 in openaux (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffd950) at dl-deps.c:64
#5  0x00007ffff7fc94e1 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fffffffd930, operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff7fca830 <openaux>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd950) at dl-catch.c:237
#6  0x00007ffff7fcacc5 in _dl_map_object_deps (map=map@entry=0x7ffff7ffe2e0, preloads=<optimized out>, npreloads=npreloads@entry=0, trace_mode=<optimized out>, open_mode=open_mode@entry=0) at dl-deps.c:232
#7  0x00007ffff7fe695e in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phnum=<optimized out>, user_entry=<optimized out>, auxv=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:1965
#8  0x00007ffff7fe3583 in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=start_argptr@entry=0x7fffffffe180, dl_main=dl_main@entry=0x7ffff7fe5040 <dl_main>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dl-sysdep.c:140
#9  0x00007ffff7fe4d6e in _dl_start_final (arg=0x7fffffffe180) at rtld.c:494
#10 _dl_start (arg=0x7fffffffe180) at rtld.c:581
#11 0x00007ffff7fe3b68 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#12 0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007fffffffe58e in ?? ()
#14 0x00007fffffffe5a1 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) 

edit : full backtrace : https://pastebin.com/grMUQiWH
Where do I look now to solve this issue ?

GDB is for the developers to debug their code. If you know C or C++ or whatever language the tool was written in, then you could use gdb to guide you into modifying the source code and fixing a bug, but gdb isn't a tool for the non-programmer. And if you aren't already familiar with the program's codebase, it is very unlikely you'll get anything useful from gdb even if you do know the language in question.

That's what i got from not understanding much from gdb output, except the file that led me to the solution below !

fixed it,
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
memset () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S:244

led me to this github  repo
I reinstalled glibc with :
sudo pacman -Syu glibc --overwrite "*"
and now everything is back to normal
edit : command modified thanks to killertofus' comment

Wow. So the hard reboot actually messed glibc up? How is that even possible? Nice find, well done!

you shouldn't syy, always syu not syy or sy* without the u  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported https://gist.github.com/vodik/5660494
